# ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException:

Tags: apache-kafka

Could you please help me how to fix this the below error while running the command in the cloudera VM 5.13

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo service kafka-server startStarting Kafka Server (kafka-server): [OK ]
 Kafka Server is running [OK]

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ /usr/bin/kafka-topics --zookeeper quickstart.cloudera:2181 --list
        SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
        SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/kafka/libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
        SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/kafka/libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
        SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
        SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]


        [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ /usr/bin/kafka-topics --create --zookeeper quickstart.cloudera:2181/kafka --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic fast-messages
        SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
        SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/kafka/libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
        SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/kafka/libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
        SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
        SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
        Error while executing topic command : replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
        [2018-08-01 10:39:31,272] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
         (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)


[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

I have installed the kafka using command line steps based on the below link from cloudera site:
               https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_installing.html

Please find the below addtional zookeeper details:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$  zookeeper-client

    Connecting to localhost:2181
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,726 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-cdh5.13.0--1, built on 10/04/2017 18:04 GMT
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,737 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:host.name=quickstart.cloudera
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,738 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_67
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,744 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,745 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,745 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../build/classes:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../lib/jline-2.11.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh5.13.0.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/etc/zookeeper/conf::/etc/zookeeper/conf:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh5.13.0.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/jline-2.11.jar
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,746 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,746 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,747 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,747 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:os.name=Linux
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,748 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,748 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,748 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:user.name=cloudera
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,749 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:user.home=/home/cloudera
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,749 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:user.dir=/home/cloudera
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,753 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeper@438] - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=30000 watcher=org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain$MyWatcher@5cd4927f
    Welcome to ZooKeeper!
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,841 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@975] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
    JLine support is enabled
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,883 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@852] - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:52573, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
    2018-08-01 10:43:18,923 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1235] - Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x164f3aeeda8001b, negotiated timeout = 30000

    WATCHER::

    WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null




    [zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] ls /brokers/ids
    [0]
    [zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1]







    Server.properties:



    # see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

    ############################# Server Basics #############################

    # The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
    broker.id=0

    # Switch to enable topic deletion or not, default value is false
    #delete.topic.enable=true

    ############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

    # The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
    # java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
    #   FORMAT:
    #     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
    #   EXAMPLE:
    #     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
    #listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

    # Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set,
    # it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
    # returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
    #advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

    # Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
    #listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

    # The number of threads handling network requests
    num.network.threads=3

    # The number of threads doing disk I/O
    num.io.threads=8

    # The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
    socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

    # The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
    socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

    # The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
    socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


    ############################# Log Basics #############################

    # A comma seperated list of directories under which to store log files
    log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

    # The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
    # parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
    # the brokers.
    num.partitions=1

    # The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
    # This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
    num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

    ############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

    # Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
    # the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
    # There are a few important trade-offs here:
    #    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
    #    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
    #    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to exceessive seeks.
    # The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
    # every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

    # The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
    #log.flush.interval.messages=10000

    # The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
    #log.flush.interval.ms=1000

    ############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

    # The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
    # be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
    # A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
    # from the end of the log.

    # The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
    log.retention.hours=168

    # A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log as long as the remaining
    # segments don't drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
    #log.retention.bytes=1073741824

    # The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
    log.segment.bytes=1073741824

    # The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
    # to the retention policies
    log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

    ############################# Zookeeper #############################

    # Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
    # This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
    # server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
    # You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
    # root directory for all kafka znodes.
    zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

    # Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
    zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `--zookeeper` setting is incorrect. It should be `--zookeeper quickstart.cloudera:2181` and not `--zookeeper quickstart.cloudera:2181/kafka`. I have just replicated this error by using a trailing `/kafka` and removing it fixed the issue.